# Issue with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, forceclose

In my android app, there is a `SurfaceView`. Whenever user touches it a short( 1 sec) animation is rendered on the `SurfaceView` by a `AsyncTask`. I face **force close** problem in two scenarios.

1. When used presses Back key while the animation is running.
2. In the arcade mode game duration is of 60 seconds. At the end of game, new activity is started. If at the end of the game , the animation is still running while the new activity is started, I get force close error message.

How can I check if the `AsyncTask` is complete i.e. the animation is over, before Back key press takes effect or new activity is started ? Using `AsyncTask.getStatus()` in a while loop is freezing the app. Or is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: before do anything you could use isFinished(), check logcat and see what causes this force close

Comment: `AsyncTask` does not have isFinished method. What I m missing here ?

Comment: I refer to isFinishing of Activity class not Asynctask, anyway if it's not a inner class of activity you don't have it. You could use this method of Activity to check if the Activity is still alive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way to wait for it to finish is like asyncTask.execute().get() ;

with this your main thread will wait this to finish

Comment: would'nt that block UI? Will it be any different from doing animation from UI thread instead ?